# python django dictionary values (for loop is in .html not in views.py)

Tags: python, django, dictionary

i want to print the values of the dictionary. here dict is in data.entityFeatures

```
{% for key in data.entityFeatures %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ key }}</td>
        <td>{{ data.entityFeatures[key] }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

i'm getting following error when i run this code

```
Could not parse the remainder: '[key]' from 'data.entityFeatures[key]'
```